# How to add a field to Access 2003 query to show results of it based on another one ?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I would like to add a 'rank' field to a query. I have a simple query that orders the results based on a field called 'score'. I want to add another field than than auto-fills with 1 for the first record, then 2, for the second, etc... so it shows a rank position. I have tried creating a field using the following - rank: [rank]+1 but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: You could port your query to a table with an autonumber so the autonumber would give you your rank. Im pretty sure however that whatever it is you are trying to achieve there are easier solutions i.e. VBA

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a good way to do this in MS-Access. Here's a link that may shed some light on this issue:

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-return-row-numbers-with-my-query.html